# multiprocessing.Process - Variable as function

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I am using the code below to parallelize the processing of a numpy array.  The target function in this case performs a simple linear stretch on the input data.  The array is segmented and then fed to the pool in chunks.  This is working quite well thanks to the numerous parallel processing with python posts.

```
        pool = [multiprocessing.Process(target=linear_stretch, args= (shared_arr,slice(i, i+step), 35, 200, 2.0)) for i in range (0, y, step)]
```

My question is, is it possible to do something like the following:

```
stretch = Linear.linear_stretch()
```

Where I create an object of the function (please correct my vocab!) and then call it in the multiprocessing.Process.

The module that the function resides in currently looks like:

```
Linear.py

import numpy

def linear_stretch(args):
    #Do some stuff
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
stretch = Linear.linear_stretch
```

In Python, functions are already first-class objects and are capable of being manipulated like any other object, or passed by reference to another variable. Note that parentheses after a function or method signals the interpreter to call the function and pass the return value, which is why:

```
stretch = Linear.linear_stretch()
```

will not work as expected.

Comment: +1. But, depending on… stuff that's hard to explain (see multiprocessing's extensions to the pickle protocol) you may or may not be able to pass a function to the child processes. Try it and see, and come back and ask for more help if it doesn't work.

Comment: Worked wonderfully.  Not sure why I did not test / read the docs...  Thanks!